# EXE BAD ACCESS in line 14 in main.m after I type randomly when program launches?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.1

I got this weird crash EXE_BAD_ACCESS error when I typed randomly by keyboard in freshly new View Based Application project in Xcode 4.1 and iOS SDK 4.3. When I press run after I created a View Based Application Project, a blank screen with come. And when I start to press keys from keyboard two to five letters ,it crashes on main.m file line no. 14.

```
9  #import "UIKit/UIKit.h"
10 
11 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
12    
13    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
14    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
15    [pool release];
16    return retVal;
17  }
```

Please help, I want to know what's going on. Any links, related posts would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Actually I found out this crash when i used UITextField in a View based application for testing purpose. When I type in UITextField, it crashes with EXE_BAD_ACCESS. But now it seems, it occurs on any applications running in Xcode 4.1 :(

Comment: Here is a question that also deals with an error on line 14: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162892/error-on-line-14-php-curl-dom]  Translation: Line 14 is not helpful unless you post your code. ;-)

Comment: Thanks Richard for point out about my code. It is normal iPhone's main .m code that usually is the same.

Comment: Enable NSZombieEnabled and try again.

Comment: Hey Jano, thanks for responding. I did try using NSZombieEnabled to YES but it didn't helped. I think its bug with Xcode4.1. If you guys have xcode4.1 with iOS4.3 SDK, please try above steps, I guess you will have above error. Any other tips?

Comment: Your code is not crashing on line 14 of `main.m`.  That is the **bottom** of your call stack.  Your code is crashing in the function at the **top** of your call stack.

Comment: Hey Adam, would u please tell me more about "Bottom" and "top" of the call stack. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this thread. It is of course a bug with Xcode 4.1 build: 4B103. https://github.com/futuretap/InAppSettingsKit/issues/75#issuecomment-2343312